# How do I change the colour of my QR code?

Tags: python, tkinter, qr-code

I want to make a QR code with python. The output is a white background with a black qr code. How do I change both of them?

```
from tkinter import *
import os
import pyqrcode

window = Tk()
window.geometry("550x350")
window.configure(bg="#0434a0")
window.title("QR Code Maker")
photo = PhotoImage(file = "logo.png")
window.iconphoto(False, photo)

def generate():
    if len(Subject.get())!=0 :
        global qr,photo
        qr = pyqrcode.create(Subject.get())
        photo = BitmapImage(data = qr.xbm(scale=8))
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("Voer een URL in...")
    try:
        showcode()
    except:
        pass

def showcode():
    imageLabel.config(image = photo)
    subLabel.config(text="QR van " + Subject.get())
```

Comment: first you should check documentation for `pyqrcode`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pyqrcode` module has not been updated for over 5 years.  Use `qrcode` module instead. Note that `qrcode` module requires `Pillow` module.

```py
...
from PIL import ImageTk
import qrcode
...
def generate():
    try:
        subject = Subject.get().strip()
        if len(subject) != 0:
            # adjust border and box_size to suit your case
            qr = qrcode.QRCode(border=2, box_size=10)
            qr.add_data(subject)
            # change fill_color and back_color to whatever you want
            img = qr.make_image(fill_color='blue', back_color='cyan')
            photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
            showcode(subject, photo)
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("Voer een URL in...")
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)

def showcode(subject, photo):
    imageLabel.config(image=photo)
    imageLabel.image = photo # keep a reference of the image to avoid garbage collection
    subLabel.config(text="QR van " + subject)
...
```

Note that I pass the photo and subject to `showcode()` instead of using global variables.

Suggest to merge the code in `showcode()` into `generate()`.

Comment: thanks, hopefully this can help someone else as well!

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of this module can be found here: [PyQRCode Module Documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/PyQRCode/moddoc.html)

It says that the various methods of this module (e.g. `png`, if you want to get the QR code as a png image) take a `background` parameter that lets you define the background color, as well as a `module_color` parameter for the code itself.

Comment: how do i inplement that in my code?

Comment: I don't have the module installed, so I can't try it; but from the documentation I would think that if you want (for instance) a blue QR code on yellow background saved as a png file, the following should do the trick: qr = pyqrcode.create(Subject.get()) qr.png('filename.png', module_color='blue', background='yellow')

Comment: `qr.eps` gets red lined, i get the following error `SyntaxError: invalid syntaxjedi`